# How to call this data piece in Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I would like to call the meters (732) piece of data from the following json API return:

```
{"results":1,"data":[{"wind":{"degrees":200,"speed_kts":6,"speed_mph":7,"speed_mps":3,"speed_kph":11},"temperature":{"celsius":16,"fahrenheit":61},"dewpoint":{"celsius":14,"fahrenheit":57},"humidity":{"percent":88},"barometer":{"hg":30.06,"hpa":1018,"kpa":101.79,"mb":1017.92},"visibility":{"miles":"Greater than 6","miles_float":6.21,"meters":"10,000+","meters_float":10000},"ceiling":{"code":"BKN","text":"Broken","feet":2400,"meters":732,"base_feet_agl":2400,"base_meters_agl":732},"elevation":{"feet":256,"meters":78},"location":{"coordinates":[-2.27495,53.353699],"type":"Point"},"icao":"EGCC","station":{"name":"Manchester Airport"},"observed":"2020-07-18T00:50:00.000Z","raw_text":"EGCC 180050Z AUTO 20006KT 9999 BKN024 16/14 Q1018","flight_category":"MVFR","clouds":[{"code":"BKN","text":"Broken","feet":2400,"meters":732,"base_feet_agl":2400,"base_meters_agl":732}],"conditions":[]}]}
```

This code doesn't seem to call it:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.checkwx.com/metar/EGCC/decoded',
  headers: { 'X-API-Key': 'apikey' },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    
    var ceiling = data.ceiling.feet;
      
      jQuery('#a53feet').html( ceiling );
    
  }
});
```

Html:

```
<span id="a53feet"></span>
```

Is it something in the call pathway (data.ceiling.feet), that isn't right?

Answer (score 0):

The json returned is an array you need to use like below

For accessing feet data

data.data[0].ceiling.feet;

For accessing meters data

data.data[0].ceiling.meters

Comment: I can't seem to get it to call the data, think it must be to do with the other script. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

If you see the console.log, data is an object which has data as an array , so for access the data that you are trying to , you need to do something like below:

```
data.data[0].ceiling.meters
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't seem to get it to call the data. Must be to do with the script. Any recommendations? Not used to using headers.

Comment: Call the data , mean call the API right? Also , what error do you get when you run this code? do you see something in console?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a console on wordpress. If you want to help further on this funded project - drop me an email (veryweatheranalytics@gmail.com),